# Updating a single cell in swift UICollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a simple hangman game that I wanted to make more elegant using a `UIcollectionview` but getting a single cell to update is causing even more of my hair to drop out!!

The logic of the code works, if I try to insert or delete a cell the app crashes and the indexPath variable prints out happily but the `UIcollectionview` cell refuses to update.

I used Xcode's storyboard to create the view and it has a named outlet and prototype cell, the view populates happily but will not change, what am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
let indexPath1 = IndexPath(item: item!, section: 0)
reloadCollectionView(indexPath: indexPath1 as NSIndexPath?)
```

then I call:

```
func reloadCollectionView(indexPath:NSIndexPath?) {
    print("reload indexPath item: \(indexPath?.item) and section: \(indexPath?.section)")
    if (indexPath != nil){
        let cell = collectionOutlet.cellForItem(at: indexPath as! IndexPath) as! ElementsCollectionViewCell

        let section = indexPath?.section

        if section == 0 {

                    cell.letterLabel.text = self.lettersArray0[(indexPath?.item)!]
                    collectionOutlet.reloadItems(at: [indexPath as! IndexPath])

                    print(" Cell text: \(cell.letterLabel.text ?? "NOWT")")
               //collectionOutlet.reloadData()
                    print("Index \(indexPath)")

}
```

Comment: Not related but why do you cast the index path to `NSIndexPath` and later back to (expected) `IndexPath`? Why do you check for section 0 although the section seems to be always 0. And why do you use so many question and exclamation marks rather than unwrapping the index path with optional bindings? This is Swift.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help so far, vadian I did that because the compiler suggested it!! ?? I will clean that up later, but when inputting the code to stackoverflow I deleted a line by mistake

Comment: Don't blame the compiler ;-) . You wrote `func reloadCollectionView(indexPath: NSIndexPath?)` rather than `func reloadCollectionView(indexPath: IndexPath?)` and `if (indexPath != nil) { ...` rather than `if let indexPath = indexPath { ...`

Comment: When inputting the code to stackoverflow I deleted a line by mistake and had the reloadItems but it stubbornly refuses, also there are other sections but I did not include them.

Comment: well spotted vadian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cellForItemAt` method is what updates your cells.  The proper way to get a cell to update is to update the model, then reload the collection view, which will call `cellForItemAt` and redraw your cell based on the model.

In your case it looks like your model is `self.lettersArray0` so make sure it has been updated before you call reload.

You can reload your cells using any of the following methods:

```
    collectionView?.reloadData()
    collectionView?.reloadItems(at: )
    collectionView?.reloadSections(sections:)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update just one cell, and not reload the whole collection view, you can do:

```
collectionOutlet.performBatchUpdates({
    collectionOutlet.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}){
    // optional closure
    print(“finished updating cell”)
}
```

[performBatchUpdates Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates)
[reloadItems Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618055-reloaditems)

Comment: I cleaned up the code before posting it, and deleted the reloadItems                //collectionOutlet.beginUpdates()
                collectionOutlet.reloadItems(at: [indexPath as! IndexPath])
                //collectionOutlet.endUpdates()
 If I leave in the begin and endUpdates the complier complains that the UIcollectionview has no member beginUpdates.

Comment: I didn’t hace Xcode to try and assume it was the same as UITableView. The method changed for collection views using the newer blocks/closures. I updated my answer with this